# JBoss datasource reference in web.xml fails

Tags: database, jboss, war, jndi, web.xml

I have the following configuration in my web.xml

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1234567890">
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/pcbDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

While I deploy my application I am getting the following error.

> 16:29:57,745 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "APP-5.3.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>       "jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"App-5.3\".\"WebArchive-5.1\".env.jdbc.pcbDB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.pcbDB]"
>   ]}

Rollback happens following that,

> 16:29:57,777 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "APP-5.3.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
>   {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>       "jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"App-5.3\".\"WebArchive-5.1\".env.jdbc.pcbDB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.pcbDB]"
>   ]}

I have corresponding datasource created in standalone.xml. From the web console Test Connection Succeeds....

`Name: pcbdb`

`JNDI: java:/jdbc/pcbDB`

And this is the datasource definition I have in standalone.xml.....

```
<!--Here is datasource config.... As I had many spaces in xml config I couldn't add it as code..... Now I have copied it by the char comes with tilt ~ -->
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/pcbDB" pool-name="pcbdb" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>pcbdb</user-name>
                        <password>passwd</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
```

Please give the solution.... For the same I have the context.lookup as well. It looks like `initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pcbDB");`... is this correct......?

Comment: Could you please add your actual data source definition? Secondly, you probably don't want `<res-auth>Application</res-auth> <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>`. Instead it should be `<res-auth>Container</res-auth>` . The container will figure out the auth method and connection pooling. No need to do that in the application, defeats the purpose actually.

Comment: I have added datasource definition, in the post......

Comment: `initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pcbDB");` succeeds I think.... But I am not very much sure as my overall deployment fails....

Comment: Okay - it has to be in your application packaging. Is this like a migration app from an older version of JBoss to a newer version? You most likely have deployment descriptors that are wanting the datasource reference to `java:comp/env/jdbc/pchDB`. This clue is provided in the error message - `jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"App-5.3\".\"WebArchive-5.1\".env.jdbc.pcbDB is missing` . Lastly, you should change `<res-auth>Application</res-auth>`  to `<res-auth>Container</res-auth>` since you have the userid/pwd defined in your datasource definition.

Comment: I was tried deploying it as,- by commenting the entire `<resource-ref>` section. Let me try the option of changing it from `Application` to `Container`. The thing it is not migration within JBoss lower version to upper. Rather it is migration from Websphere to JBoss. With respect to these,- `resource-ref` I have `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` that is to be migrated to JBoss. When I had probe about it, it's said like to ignore. Also I have `ibm-web-ext.xmi`. Maybe I should file about these as another question. But this is my scenario.

Comment: Okay, migrating from Websphere to JBoss will require many changes and generally quite large effort. Most of the JEE6 implementation stacks are going to be different, so this is just one piece of the puzzle. By the JBoss won't recognize `ibm-web-bnd.xmi`, I don't even know what that file is but I know JBoss won't read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDNI lookup fails for this,- `java:comp/env/jdbc/pcbDB`

JNDI lookup for this string,- `java:/jdbc/pcbDB` succeeds....